# Unable to install Scrot on Linux - no package available

Tags: python, linux

I am trying to run a python script with locateonscreen in it.

However it errors as pyautogui needs scrot and I cannot install this. I have tried

```
sudo apt-get install scrot
```

and get a 'Package scrot has no installation candidate' error.

I have checked it is already installed by running a scrot test.png command and confirmed it is not.

Is there any other available installer. I did look at building from the source code and that didn't work either although I suspect that is as it is something I have never done before.

I did look at building from the source code and that didn't work either although I suspect that is as it is something I have never done before.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: That command works just fine for me on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. What OS and what version are you running? (You can check by executing `lsb_release -a` in a terminal) Perhaps your package sources are outdated. Try to run `sudo apt-get update` before attempting that install command again.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS as well. I have run sudo apt-get update as well. Thanks for the suggestions though. It is a new build. Is there something obvious I should be doing (like adding other repositories)